# How to detect stack smashing in C with Ecplise

Tags: c, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have big code in C that when I run it I got error `*** stack smashing detected***; <unknown> terminated`

But when I compile this code with `-fno-stack-protector` everything works fine.

THat strange because if the code damage the stack the process dooesn't need to work as I exptect.

Is there any way (with gcc-ecplise debugger) to find out what is the line that make to  this error?

Comment: Corrupting the stack results in undefined behaviour. Any expected behaviour you may have, including "should break", is not correct.

Comment: Doesn't the debugger catch the termination? What does the call-stack look like when (if) the debugger catches it?

Comment: Stack smashing does not always create errors.  But then again, might in the future.  This is what makes these bugs hard to reproduce and locate.  That's why stack protection was invented.

Comment: If you are running on Linux, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is a very good tool for helping to find such problems.

Comment: As for how to fix such problems, well the easiest way is to not let them happen to begin with, by using validation of all arrays and pointers and their lengths and indexes. But also by not writing a lot of code at once without testing. Instead just write a small and simple piece of code, test it to make sure it works fine, and when it does continue with the next little part. That way makes it much easier to figure out when and where a problem is introduced. If you use a versioning system you could roll back until the error disappears to help you narrow down the location of the problem.

Comment: You should also compile with -Wall.  Sometimes the compiler can tell you when you are doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

> THat strange because if the code damage the stack the process dooesn't need to work as I exptect.

Smashing stack is undefined behavior, so *anything* can happen, including the program appearing to work correctly for some inputs and with some combinations of compilation flags.

> Is there any way (with gcc-ecplise debugger) to find out what is the line that make to this error?

You can't determine the *line* that causes stack smashing, but you should be able to determine the *function* in which this is happening, and then (if the bug is still not obvious) reduce the body of this function to just the statement which causes the stack buffer overflow.

To do this, compile with `-g`, run the program under GDB (or Eclipse), and use `where` command at crash point.